# Loopback 3 - FormData with file - 422 ValidationError

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, loopbackjs, axios

I'm using React+Redux in front-end and loopback3 in back-end.
I have a simple form with text inputs and one file input.
I create the formData as usual

`const formToSend = new FormData(document.getElementById("form_add_news"));`

then I send it to axios

```
return axios.post(*url*, action.formData,{
        params:{
            access_token:localStorage.getItem("users_token")
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response
        })
        .catch(e => {
            return e.response
        })
```

Here is the request sent :

```
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryiBetnol46iuFG9Pt
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
> 
> efzef

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryiBetnol46iuFG9Pt
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="background_img"; filename="bs.png"
> Content-Type: image/png
> 
> 
>------WebKitFormBoundaryfDIsq7k9dwZtFjpq
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"
>
> <p>zevzev</p>
>
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryiBetnol46iuFG9Pt
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="users_id"
> 
> 5
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryiBetnol46iuFG9Pt--
>
```

Request headers

```
> Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundaryiBetnol46iuFG9Pt
> ...
```

But I always get 422 ValidationError "title": cannot be blank, "content" cannot be blank...

I tried to check in 'before save' hook but there is nothing from my form :( 
It seems like the form is not received at all.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting a 422, it means that loopback is not processing the input. So 'before save' hook wont be called since loopback wont save any data in the first place.

You can however try the 'beforeRemote' hook. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html

```
// enter the remote method's name in place of '**'. '**' will call the hook before all methods of the model 

    Model.beforeRemote('**', (ctx, data, next) => { 

    // ctx.args.ARG_NAME has the data you posted
    next();
  });
```

Can you share your loopback code for the model. I feel that title is not set to be accepted as a form-data input